# Invoking setter with return value from invoked getter, exception:

Tags: c#, .net, invoke

I'm attempting to do something like this:

```
object value = sourceProperty.Invoke(this, new object[] { });
targetProperty.Invoke(target, new object[] { value });
```

where **source/targetProperty** values are **MethodInfo** objects. At the time that this code is executed, there is already a guarantee that the properties are of the same type, and that both the **this** object and the **target** object have those properties on them.

This works most of the time, but I'm running into an exception when the property type is **int**:

*"TargetException: Object does not match target type."*

Any idea what could be going on here?

**EDIT: This is resolved, see comments.**

Comment: Is your source property returning the same type as the targetProperty is expecting? It looks like you should cast the value to int explicitily.

Comment: Yes, I've already checked the source and the target properties to verify that they are the same type. Casting to int explicitly isn't an option here I think, because there are many types of objects that could potentially come through this function.

However, as a test, I did add an **if** block that would check the type of the value, and if it is int, it would just pass in a hard coded **(int)6**, and the same issue persisted. Could there be an issue with this and value types, perhaps?

Comment: Document your question better.  Explain why you don't use PropertyInfo and what the actual 'properties' look like.

Comment: That exception could be raised if the "target" instance has no method of type "targetProperty". Can you verify this?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this and your explanation, provide more code to we know what is targetProperty exactly and what is in it's type.

Comment: It turns out I was using the PropertyInfo[] from the **this** object instead of the **target** when I was trying to find the property that matches the name of the source property. The target object did actually have the property it was supposed to have, and the property types matched, and the types of the object returned from the source property matched the target property (which was erroneously the setter of the **this** object instead of the setter of the **target** object), so nothing pointed to this. I noticed the issue while formatting the block of code for an edit to my question.

Comment: @Chrensli: for the benefit of those who may encounter this or a similar issue, please post your fix as an answer and accept it. :)

Comment: I've answered my question, but I cannot accept the answer for 2 days. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was using the **PropertyInfo[]** from the **this** object instead of the **target** when I was trying to find the property that matches the name of the source property.

The target object did actually have the property it was supposed to have, and the property types matched, and the types of the object returned from the source property matched the target property (which was erroneously the setter of the this object instead of the setter of the target object), so nothing pointed to this.

I noticed the issue while formatting the block of code for an edit to my question.